# Hiding an operator in Ada while still using it in the package body

Tags: operators, ada

I need guidance on hiding an operator in Ada, while still calling it from the package body where the type was declared.

I have a type within a package where a few of the intrinsic operators are hidden by marking the operator definition as abstract, because semantically it's nonsense. However I still need the operators in the body, so that other operations can be calculated more efficiently than their workarounds. Is there a way to mark the operator as not abstract within the body, even though it is abstract in the spec? Or would I need to declare a new, equivalent function, and import from Intrinsics?

The operators in question are `*` and `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t believe you can "mark the operator as not abstract within the body".

A reasonably neat way of re-importing the intrinsic would be

```ada
package Abstracting is
   type T is new Integer;
   function "+" (L, R : T) return T is abstract;
   function Add (L, R : T) return T;
end Abstracting;
```

(I’m making a guess about your actual type - it has to be visibly numeric, or `"+"`, `"/"` wouldn’t be a problem in the first place).

Then,

```ada
package body Abstracting is

   package Intrinsics is
      function "+" (L, R : T) return T with Import, Convention => Intrinsic;
   end Intrinsics;
```

OK, that re-imports `"+"`. Now make it visible:

```ada
   use Intrinsics;

   function Add (L, R : T) return T is
   begin
      return L + R;
```

uses the version of `"+"` from package `Intrinsics` (I tried putting the `use` inside `Add` but it didn’t work. Must be treading pretty close to the edge here :)

```ada
   end Add;
end Abstracting;
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically one makes the public definition private and only declares the operations that are meaningful to the abstraction. This leaves the undefined but intrinsic operations of the full type available in the body:

```
package P is
   type T is private;
   function "+" (Left : T; Right : T) return T;
   function "-" (Left : T; Right : T) return T;
private -- P
   type T is range ...;
end P;
```

The difficulty with this approach is not with using the undefined operations but when you need to use the intrinsic operations that you've overridden: "+" and "-" in this case. This is usually solved by deriving T, converting values to the parent type to perform the operations, and converting back to T:

```
private -- P
   type Raw is range ...;
   type T is new Raw;
end P;
```

Then you can use "+" and "-" for Raw in the pkg body:

```
function "+" (Left : T; Right : T) return T is
   (T (Raw (Left) + Raw (Right) ) );
```